# EmberJS Route to 'single' getting JSONP

Tags: api, ember.js, jsonp, tumblr, router

I'm having trouble with EmberJS to create a single view to posts based on the ID, but not the ID of the array, I actually have a ID that comes with the json I got from Tumblr API.

So the ID is something like '54930292'.

Next I try to use this ID to do another jsonp to get the post for this id, it works if you open the api and put the id, and actually if you open the single url with the ID on it, works too, the problem is:

When, on the front page for example, I click on a link to go to the single, it returns me nothing and raise a error.

But if you refresh the page you get the content.

Don't know how to fix and appreciate some help :(

I put online the code: http://tkrp.net/tumblr_test/

Comment: I would be easier to help if you moved the code to [jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com), to allow live editing,debugging,etc.

Comment: Sorry, here: http://jsbin.com/okezum/2/edit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you were getting was because the `SingleRoute` was being generated as an `ArrayController` but the json response was not an Array.

```
App.SingleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

});
```

Further note that the `model` hook is not fired when using `linkTo` and other helpers. This because Ember assumes that if you linked to a model, the model is assumed to be as specified, and it directly calls setupController with that model. In your case, you need to still load the individual post. I added the `setupController` to the route to do this.

```
App.SingleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.TKRPTumblr.find(params.id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, id) {
    App.TKRPTumblr.find(id)
    .then(function(data) {
      controller.set('content', data.response);    
    });
  }
});
```

I changed the single post template a bit to reflect how the json response. One final change I made was to directly return the `$.ajax`. Ember understands jQuery promises directly, so you don't need to do any parsing.

Here is the updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/okezum/5/).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! So if I get this error again in other controller I just need to specify to Ember saying it's an Object or other kind and then setupController properly?

Comment: You're Welcome! It depends but to use ember's binding you generally want one of `ObjectController` or `ArrayController`.

Comment: Ok :D nice, and about the controller.set, why you used data.respose instead only data or data.posts to send the posts and how Ember get the exactly post from that? i'm trying to debug this part to know what happens haha

Comment: Found, but there is a catch :) if you refresh the page, it load the first post, not the actual post haha

Answer (score 0):

I modified: http://jsbin.com/okezum/6/edit
Did this to "fix" the refresh single page error:

```
setupController: function(controller, id) {
    if(typeof id === 'object'){
        controller.set('content', id.response);
    }else{
        App.TKRPTumblr.find(id)
        .then(function(data) {
            controller.set('content', data.response);    
        });
    }
}
```

modified the setupController, since I was getting a object when refreshing the page and a number when clicking the `linkTo`

Dont know if it's the best way to do that :s